# Custom Log 500 error in Laravel 10 (Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

### When I upgrade from Laravel 9 to Laravel 10 custom log stop working

This is how I handle my Custom Log

---

First I added the log in config -> logging
I edit channels by add bellow code

```
        'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['mysql', 'single'],
        'ignore_exceptions' => false,
         ],

        'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'custom',
        'handler' => App\Logging\MySQLLoggingHandler::class,
        'via' => App\Logging\MySQLCustomLogger::class,
        'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
        ],
```

---

**Then I create table and model with name Log**

1- Log Schema

```
   Schema::create('logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->longText('message');
        $table->longText('context');
        $table->string('level')->index();
        $table->string('level_name');
        $table->string('channel')->index();
        $table->string('record_datetime');
        $table->longText('extra');
        $table->longText('formatted');
        $table->string('remote_addr')->nullable();
        $table->string('user_agent')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

2- Log Model

```
php artisan make:model Logs
```

---

**Then I create Logging folder in app with two file**

1-MySQLCustomLogger.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Logging;

use Monolog\Logger;
use App\Logging\MySQLLoggingHandler;

class MySQLCustomLogger
{
   /**
   * Create a custom Monolog instance.
   *
   * @param  array  $config
   * @return \Monolog\Logger
   */
   public function __invoke(array $config)
   {
      $logger = new Logger("MySQLLoggingHandler");
      return $logger->pushHandler(new MySQLLoggingHandler());
   }
}
```

2-MySQLLoggingHandler.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Logging;

use App\Models\Log;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler;

class MySQLLoggingHandler extends AbstractProcessingHandler
{
    /**
    * Create a custom Monolog instance.
    *
    * @param  array  $config
    * @return \Monolog\Logger
    */
    public function __construct($level = Logger::DEBUG, $bubble = true) 
    {
       parent::__construct($level, $bubble);
    }


    protected function write(array $record): void

    { 
       $logs = new Logs();  
       $logs->message = $record['message'];
       $logs->context = json_encode($record['context']);
       $logs->level = $record['level'];
       $logs->level_name = $record['level_name'];
       $logs->channel = $record['channel'];
       $logs->record_datetime = $record['datetime']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
       $logs->extra = json_encode($record['extra']);
       $logs->formatted = $record['formatted'];
       $logs->remote_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
       $logs->user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
       $logs->save();   
}
```

**Then add the log to controller as**

```
Log::channel('mysql')->info('This is test');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fix it after read the format of write Method in [`AbstractProcessingHandler`](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/main/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php).
In `MySQLLoggingHandler.php`, I change the type of array in write Method to `LogRecord` and import the `Monolog\LogRecord;`

```
use Monolog\LogRecord;


protected function write(LogRecord $record): void
{ 
  $test = new Test();
  $logs->message = $record['message'];
  $test->save();
}
```